# SQL Left Joining four different tables

Tags: sql, left-join, adventureworks

From AdventureWorks2012, I want to write a query using the `Sales.SalesOrderHeader`, `Sales.Customer`, `Sales.Store`, and `Person.Person` tables, showing the `SalesOrderID`, `StoreName`, the customer’s first and last name as `CustomerName` and the salesperson’s first and last names as `SalesPersonName`.  I want to do a left join with `Sales.Customer` to the `Sales.Store` and `Person.Person` tables.

Here is my work so far.  However, the `CustomerName` and `SalesPersonName` both have the same information when they should be different.

```
SELECT soh.SalesOrderID, ST.Name AS StoreName, pp.[PersonType], pp.[FirstName] + [LastName] AS CustomerName,
pp.[FirstName] + [LastName] AS SalesPersonName
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
JOIN Sales.Customer SC ON soh.SalesOrderID = sc.CustomerID
JOIN Sales.Store ST ON sc.CustomerID = ST.BusinessEntityID
JOIN Person.Person PP ON ST.BusinessEntityID = PP.BusinessEntityID
WHERE Persontype LIKE 'SP%'
```

Comment: you're selecting two identical things with different aliases, how would it be different? `pp.[FirstName] + [LastName] AS CustomerName, 
pp.[FirstName] + [LastName] AS SalesPersonName`

Comment: A suggestion: build your query bit by bit. Start with just one table, check the result of that query. Join a second one, check the result of that query. This way, you have much more chance of pinpointing the exact error.

Comment: And what @kostyan says, please check that! If you ask the same thing twice and stick a different name on it, that will not change the contents...

Answer (score 1):

You're getting bad results, because your joins are wrong. You should join on fields, that represent a relation between the 2 table. For example:

```
JOIN Sales.Customer sc ON soh.CustomerID = sc.CustomerID
```

Comment: thanks.  the query executes, but 0 rows are affected and I can't figure out why

Comment: Did you fix the other joins as well? If so, please edit your question, and update that sql, so we can see what is wrong now.

Comment: @user3047713 No rows are affected, which is correct. It is a `SELECT`, it only returns rows.